# HQL query returns no results

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm beginner in HQL (and hibernate at all). I need help with a simple **ManyToMany** relation:

**Video - video_category - Category**

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "3-20 chars!")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    private List<Video> videos;

    //Getters and setters
```

**Video.java**

```
@Entity
public class Video {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String url;

    private Date publishDate;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "video_category", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "video_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private List<Category> categories;
```

**And this query gives me no results**

```
Query query = sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "from Video vid inner join vid.categories cat where vid.id = :category");
query.setParameter("category", category);
```

If I send just `.createQuery("from Video")` - it gives me all videos (so the connection to DB is fine). `Category` a `video_category` tables have some data too. I think, there will be a mistake in joining tables or somewhere.

Edit:

I'm trying to achieve to go in table `video_category` and look there for `category_id`. In SQL like this: `select * from Video join video_category on Video.id=video_category.video_id where category_id = 2`

Comment: `ug`(why the hell is it named this way, instead of `video`) is the alias for the video. And you're trying to find a video whose ID is equal to the parameter `category`. Either you also chose a very weird name for this parameter which should be named `videoId`, or it's in fact the ID of a category, and trying to find a vide that has the ID of a category is very very strange. What are you trying to achieve? What is `category`? Why don't you just use session.get(Video.class, id)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I will edit it. It is a ManyToMany relation and I'm trying to join table `video_category` and look there for `category_id`. In SQL it is something like this: `select * from Video join video_category on Video.id=video_category.video_id where category_id = 2`.

Comment: Then you need `where u.id = :category`. `ug` is the alias for video. `u` is the alias for category. Everything would be much clearer with good naming: `select video from Video video inner join video.categories category where category.id = :catagoryId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the alias for the video instead of using the alias for the category. Use batter names, and it should become much more obvious:

```
select video 
from Video video 
inner join video.categories category 
where category.id = :categoryId
```